# Different Python versions on Terminal command line vs. Sublime

Tags: python, string, sublimetext2, python-3.4

I try to run this:

```
import string

myStr = "This$, (is) my string."

table = string.maketrans( '', '', )
cleanedStr = myStr.translate(table, "(){}<>,:!?_*!$%/.")

print(cleanedStr)
```

It works for me if I build it from Sublime Text 2, but if I run it in the Terminal command line with `python test_script.py` I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_script.py", line 6, in <module>
    table = string.maketrans( '', '', )
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'
```

My Python version is:

```
Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (x86_64)| (default, Oct 20 2015, 14:27:51) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
```

I don't understand why Python doesn't seem to be able to do `import string` when I run it from the command line, but it works when I call it from within Sublime.

Comment: `string.maketrans` doesn't exist in Python 3.4. You must be using an earlier Python version in the case where it works. Probably Python 2.

Comment: pretty sure your sublime is running Py 2

Comment: I don't think so, I use `print("Hello world.")` there.

Comment: Ok, yeah you're right, if I check my version with `import sys  print(sys.version)` it tells me it's version 2.7. Thanks!